# Critical points and the Foundation Axiom

Tags: set-theory, mathematical-philosophy

(Note:  This question is related to my previous mathoverflow question, "Critical Points in $ZF$ without Choice".)

In the *Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy* entry "Non-Wellfounded Set Theory" (Section 2.2, "The Foundation Axiom"), one has the following statement (my comments regarding it are in brackets):

> The Foundation Axiom ($FA$) may be stated in different ways.  Here are some formulations; their equivalence in the presence of the other [$ZF$?] axioms is a standard result of elementary [$ZF$?] set theory [the last two, (4) and (5), are particularly relevant to my previous question]:
>
> (4).  For every set $x$, there is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $x$$\in$$V_{\alpha}$. [seemingly necessary for Asaf's proof in his answer to my previous question]
>
> (5).  $V_{[ZF?]}$=$WF$ [the class of well-founded sets].

Question 1: Can the equivalence of (4) and (5) (and their equivalence to $FA$) be proved in $ZF$ alone, without recourse to Choice?

Question 2: Regarding (5) (i.e. $V$=$WF$--my comment excluded), does $V$=$V_{ZF}$?  I ask this question because of the following: in the  Daghighi, Golshani, Hamkins, and Jerabek paper, "The Role of the Foundation Axiom in the Kunen Inconsistency", they claim (and prove, in $GBC^{-f}$ and in $ZFC^{-f}$) that the Kunen inconsistency (in the following form: "There is no nontrivial $\Sigma_1$-elementary embedding $j$:$WF$$\rightarrow$$WF$.") holds for $WF$.  If $V_{ZF}$=$WF$, then it seems that there must be a way to adjust their proof so that it doesn't need Choice (in which case, a major open problem will have seemingly been solved).  What, if anything, is wrong with this picture?

Comment: Where do you think the axiom of choice is being used in the proof of equivalence between Foundations and the two statements you wrote?

Comment: What is $V_{ZF}$? (I also second Asaf's question - I don't see where choice is being used in the standard argument that $(4)$ is equivalent to Foundation).

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  I wished to see if (4), (5) , and $FA$ could be proved equivalent  in  $ZF$ alone--I am not presuming Choice is needed (as Noah was kind enough to point out in his comment).  I presume, then, that (5) can be proved equivalent  to (4) and $FA$ in $ZF$ and in (5), $V$=$V_{ZF}$, $V_{ZF}$ being the universe generated by the axioms of $ZF$ (as opposed to the universe $V_{ZFC}$, which is the universe generated by the axioms of $ZFC$)?

Comment: I think Asaf and Noah have answered your question: The usual proofs of these equivalences don't use choice. But your last comment raises another question: What do you mean when you say a universe is "generated" by some axioms? One possibility is that you mean a universe that is assumed to satisfy those axioms but is not further specified. Your use of the definite article ("*the* universe generated by ...") suggests that you have something else in mind, but I can't imagine what.

Comment: @AndreasBlass:  I really should have said 'satisfied by $V$'.  By 'generated', I meant  'generated by the axioms and theorems in 'the' cumulative hierarchy'.  Since one can use the term 'model' as 'universe', the axioms 'generate' a proper class of similar, but distinct models that satisfy a given first-order theory.  Apologies.

Comment: No need for apology. "Satisfied" is passive, "generated" is active. Shouldn't a more active role for a set of axioms be invited? Questioned, surely. Dismissed, possibly. I look at the Greek root for "generated" and I look at a universe and I am brought to cusp. If that universe is more than combinatorial, then I am forced to ask: how did those extra propositions arise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, this is the answer:

Suppose $V$ is a model of $ZF$ minus Foundation (call this theory "$ZF^-$"). Then the following are equivalent:

- $V$ satisfies Foundation - that is, $V$ is in fact a model of all of $ZF$.
- "$V=\bigcup_{\alpha\in ON} V_\alpha$" - that is, for each $x\in V$ there is some $\alpha\in ON^V$ such that $V\models x\in V_\alpha$.

The usual proof goes through without any changes - in particular, Choice is not used anywhere.

As far as the result of Daghighi, Golshani, Hamkins, and Jerabek you cite: this seems orthogonal to the (non-)use of choice in the above theorem. Their result is that if $V$ is a model of - say - $ZFC^-$, then there is no nontrivial $\Sigma_1$-definable elementary embedding from $WF^V$ to $WF^V$. I don't see how the observation above has anything to do with removing choice from this argument.

Comment: Regarding  the second point in your answer--this is because $WF^{V}$ (since $WF^{V}$ is a model of $ZFC^{-f}$) is a class of well-ordered sets (since Choice still holds for $WF^{V}$)?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Yes, but I still don't see the connection - how does the fact that "$\bigcup V_\alpha=V$ is equivalent to foundation over ZF" have anything to do with extending the result mentioned to ZF?

Comment: Since $V_{ZF}$=$WF$ and $V_{ZFC}$=$WO$ ($WO$=the class of all well-ordered sets), the $V$ for $ZFC^{-f}$ is still a class of well-orderd sets (since Choice still holds for $ZFC^{-f}$).  Recall that in the paper mentioned, the theorem ("Work in $GBC^{-f}$ or $ZFC^{-f}$.  Then there is no nontrivial $\Sigma_1$-elementary embedding  $j$:$WF$$\rightarrow$$WF$.") was billed as stating that the Kunen inconsistency still holds for the class $WF$ of $GBC^{-f}$ or $ZFC^{-f}$.  Though true, it seems to me a bit of 'false advertising', since the '$WF$' for $GBC^{-f}$ and $ZFC^{-f}$ are

Comment: (cont.) really classes of well-ordered sets, and the Kunen inconsistency holds of course for these.  Since  for $<$$WF$,$\in$$>$, $\in$ is  rigid for $WF$ (since $WF$ is a transitive class), I conjectured that there are no nontrivial elementary embeddings $j$:$WF$$\rightarrow$$WF$ and asked essentially whether the results of Theorem 1 of the paper in question can, in fact be extended to the class $WF$ (a closer look at the theorem suggests--probably not....).

Comment: ($WF$ is a transitive class with respect to $\in$)

Comment: Considering that my question has been downvoted, I am considering deleting the question.  Since I have accepted your answer, I am not sure whether I should.  Please advise. Thanks.